# Is there a way to render the scrt:conversationBody component inside a custom aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

we are trying to create a custom Aura component that integrates with the `scrt:conversationBody` component (on `Edit Page` it is called `Enhanced Conversation`) used in Messaging In-App and Web for Messaging Session in the Service Console in Salesforce.

So, we wanted to understand how to declare it with the appropriate tag and parameters inside a custom Aura component so that it renders correctly and we can interact with it. Is there a way to do that? Our purpose is to create a new component that extends `srct:conversationBody`.

Thanks in advance!